# How can I "spy" on an Apache web server's response to server-side code like PHP or JavaScript?

Tags: php, apache-2.4, javascript

I'm trying to debug a problem with a file upload strategy and don't know whether there's an issue with directory permissions / ownership or the scripts. ... I've tried both PHP and JavaScript and can't seem to get enough information to track down what's happening, despite tail -f on both the error and access logs for the domain.

**NOTE:**
I've tried to increase the LogLevel on the php module - I'm running 7 - but I can't seem to find the module name.

This is on Fedora 31 /32 and there's a file /etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf that says it's looking for mod_php7, and a comment that there's no mod_php in the default configuration. However, I KNOW php is running. . . NEITHER mod_php nor mod_php7 are acceptable in LogLevel - perhaps it's not loaded until / when needed?!

So, I enabled `debug` `LogLevel` on the directory instead. Lots of data, no idea why it's not working. ...Trying to increase the `LogLevel`, but this seems to be headed the wrong way - too much noise! And I don't ever see the data passed.

**Update on Logging**

I increased the `LogLevel` only for the directory that kicks off the upload to `trace5`. I got a lot more data and still nothing on either file access or why the upload fails.

...Do browser side things like Web Consoles (Firefox is what I'm using) have anything to share here? I would think not, but I'm a novice at this!

**Configuration Data**

```
**# rpm -qa | grep php**
php-fpm-7.4.8-2.fc32.x86_64
php-json-7.4.8-2.fc32.x86_64
php-xml-7.4.8-2.fc32.x86_64
php-mbstring-7.4.8-2.fc32.x86_64
php-opcache-7.4.8-2.fc32.x86_64
php-pgsql-7.4.8-2.fc32.x86_64
php-ldap-7.4.8-2.fc32.x86_64
php-cli-7.4.8-2.fc32.x86_64
php-pdo-7.4.8-2.fc32.x86_64
php-mysqlnd-7.4.8-2.fc32.x86_64
php-sodium-7.4.8-2.fc32.x86_64
php-7.4.8-2.fc32.x86_64
php-common-7.4.8-2.fc32.x86_64
**# rpm -qa | grep apache**
apache-commons-collections-3.2.2-16.fc32.noarch
apache-commons-daemon-1.2.2-2.fc32.x86_64
apache-commons-pool-1.6-22.fc32.noarch
apache-commons-dbcp-1.4-29.fc32.noarch
python3-certbot-apache-1.6.0-1.fc32.noarch
**# rpm -qa | grep httpd**
httpd-tools-2.4.43-5.fc32.x86_64
httpd-manual-2.4.43-5.fc32.noarch
httpd-filesystem-2.4.43-5.fc32.noarch
fedora-logos-httpd-30.0.2-4.fc32.noarch
httpd-2.4.43-5.fc32.x86_64
```

Advice, please!

Comment: Start with installing a php script with nothing but "phpinfo();".  It'll show you (when you browse to that page) a lot of information concerning your configuration.

Comment: How did you install PHP?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I installed it the usual way on Fedora Server - by installing Fedora Server. It comes with. I know it's being called because of the browser's Web Console contents... What I can't see are when it tries to touch disk space.... I'm about to update the comment to include more about my trace efforts...

Comment: I just installed Fedora Server. It doesn't install either Apache or PHP. How did you manage to get them?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Hmmm... That confuses me! Well, I can tell you that I use all the standard Fedora tools like DNF and sometimes yum, and, more rarely these days, rpm. I know for sure I didn't explicitly install these this time, which, well, IDK what to say about that but I'll be glad to share the installed package list above! ... Right now, family member with issues, so it'll take another hour or so to do.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Sorry for the delay - a friend had a home invasion robbery and they tied him up, the police had to free him! Anyway, got the data up. ... As for how I got these packages, I've since remembered: THIS system, unlike several recent installs, wasn't from scratch but was an "upgrade" because the version wasn't so old. IE # dnf upgrade...

Answer (score 0):

A few ideas.

Turn up the debug logging in apache.

Run strace against the process.

Comment: I've used strace many times but don't have a clue how I run it against an image apache starts during the server / web browser exchange..